# The dates and checking for a planning

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a problem concerning the checking of my dates.

Example, my motorbike number 000001 is in revision from **30/08/2019** to **03/09/2019**. The recording is good. (no problem)

However, if I add a revision on **02/09/2019** to **03/09/2019**, I would like to add an error message explaining that the motorbike is already in revision.

[image]

My function index() is like this:

```
public function index()
{
    $revisions = Revision::oldest()->paginate(5);
    return view('admin.revisions.index', compact('revisions'))
      ->with('i', (request()->input('page',1) -1)*5);
}
```

I think my problem is in my function store()???

**Edit:**

```
$date_revision_start = $request->get('date_revision_start');
$date_revision_end = $request->get('date_revision_end');
$garage = $request->get('garage');
 $fk_motorbike = $request->get('fk_motorbike');



 $conflict = Revision::whereDate('fk_motorbike', $request->get('fk_motorbike'))->whereDate('date_revision_start', "<=" , $date_revision_start);

 $conflict2 = Revision::whereDate('fk_motorbike', $request->get('fk_motorbike'))->whereDate('date_revision_start', "<=" , $date_revision_end)->whereDate('date_revision_end', ">=", $date_revision_end)->first();


        if(isset($conflict2) || isset($conflict)){
            return redirect()->route('revisions.index')
             ->with('error', 'duplicate');
        }


       else{
        Revision::create($request->all());
            return redirect()->route('revisions.index')
                ->with('success', 'new data created successfully');
        }
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: i think you forget a ) in `where('fk_motorbike', $request->get('yourFKFieldForMotorBikeOnForm)->...`

Comment: @porloscerros Ψ: Indeed... My problem is now "Call to a member function whereDate() on null" ??

Comment: are you validating `newStart` and `newEnd` as required?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ: Ah no.... Ok, I add.. I have to add elsewhere also??

Comment: I asked because if that data is not required, you would have to make that whereDate conditional. With the [when()](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Concerns/BuildsQueries.html#method_when) method  for example

Comment: You would have a null in the where date if you haven't renamed your form elements `newStart` and `newEnd` on your form... or changed the `$request->get()` to whatever your actual names are.  These fields should be required on the form, and validate as required before running the queries - but that shouldn't change the answer.  Also - please remember to set an actual field on the form for the Bike id and match it in the request (IE remove my silly `yourFKFieldForMotorBikeOnForm` and replace with a real variable from your form)  :-)

Comment: @Watercayman: Yes, I saw... I always have an error message :-( `Call to a member function whereDate() on string`. I have edited my first message...

Comment: Ahh.  You'll need to convert the incoming dates (from the form) to Carbon objects.  Review the docs on Carbon - **create from string** to make it fit whatever format is coming in from your form.  You are very close those i think.  One of them - parse, createFromFormat, etc will work for you depending on your format

Comment: @Watercayman: Ah ok, I'm looking at that. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Yep, the dates in doesn't look as standard format, i think this could do what you want `Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $request->newStart);`. Also this line `protected $dates = ['newStart', 'newEnd'];` in your model can make the treatment of dates easier  (replacing with your model fields names)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use a similar test to see if the bike is already in revision, to the one that you have designed previously to test against bikes in revision for today.

There are a few ways to do this, but I will write the simplest one even though it may not be the most efficient.

I would take the start and end date from your input on the second bike (I don't know what this is, but I'm assuming you have someone trying to input a start and end date for a motorbike revision - let's call it `newStart` and `newEnd` for the input dates)

```
$newStart = $request->get('newStart');
$newEnd = $request->get('newEnd');
```

Then, run through both of these dates to see if either coincide with the current revision for this motorbike (you can do this in one query, but I'm expanding just to show what you are after):

```
$conflict = Revision::where('fk_motorbike', $request->get('yourFKFieldForMotorBikeOnForm))
 ->whereDate('date_revision_start', "<=" , $newStart)
 ->whereDate('date_revision_end', ">=", $newStart)->first();

$conflict2 = Revision::where('fk_motorbike', $request->get('yourFKFieldForMotorBikeOnForm))
->whereDate('date_revision_start', "<=" , $newEnd)
->whereDate('date_revision_end', ">=", $newEnd)->first();
```

If either of these is in revision, then send back the fail message:

```
if(isset($conflict2) || isset($conflict)){
     return redirect()->route('motorbikes.index')
             ->with('error', 'duplicate');
 }
```

This code is not exact, but I think this is all you need to determine if there is a conflict (you don't need the `$exists` stuff for determining a conflict, but you may need some code to store the new revision if there is NO conflict).  You'll need to play with this a bit to get it working for you.

Comment: Thank you a lot, I have a question, I add newStart & newEnd on my table revisions????

Comment: No, these are just the dates that are coming from your form (which I randomly named variables for).  I assume someone tries to add a revision on a form.  This revision will have a start date on the form (`newStart`), and end date on the form (`newEnd`) and the motorbike id.  The dates in the table revisions do not change, we are just comparing the form fields (`$newStart`, `$newEnd`) to those dates (`date_revision_start/end`).

Comment: the code works but I always have the same problem. I have edited my first message with the code and a screenshot.

Comment: There are a couple of problems in the edit code.  First - you are using `where` instead of `whereDate`, which is going to cause problems.  But more importantly, that whole section above the first `$conflict` is unnecessary (I think).  The `if(isset($conflict2) || isset($conflict)){ ... }` line is *already* telling you if there is a conflict.  I suggest you add a `else` right below that and create a new Revision since you'll know there is no conflict at this point.  And remove all the `$exists` stuff, since we haven't checked if conflict yet.  IE start at `$conflict` and then add create at END

Comment: My "else" for the create of recordings seems to be incorrect? (i have edited my first message again). I always have the message 'duplicate' for all actions

Comment: No, the else is OK.  Your first `$conflict` is returning a non-null value every time because it is not correct.  It is returning a BUILDER object (not null, so it will return 'duplicate' every time).  You need to copy the code correctly - it is only part of the code, and thus is a builder object, not an actual database query. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should have fields like start_date and end_date when submitting form.

use this for Revisions.

```
$revisions= Revisions::where('date_revision_start','>=',$request->start_date)
->orWhere('date_revision_end','<=',$request->end_date)
->first();

if($revisions){
 code...
}
else{
return error......
}
```

Comment: I have tried this but I still have the same problem. It's perhaps here my problem? `if($revisions){ return redirect()->route('revisions.index') ->with('error', 'duplicate'); }
        
  else{Revision::create($request->all());return redirect()->route('revisions.index')
                ->with('success', 'new data created successfully');}`ata created successfully');